# How can several .ts files be converted to one (non-fragmented) .mp4 file using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming

### Problem Description

The video player I'm using doesn't support `.ts` files, but it does play `.mp4` files, so I'd like to use ffmpeg to convert my `.ts` files to `.mp4` files.

### Goal Solution

Use ffmpeg to download several `.ts` segments and transcode them into an `.mp4` file that I'd load into my video player. Rinse and repeat. It'd add a delay of 10-20 seconds, but that's fine.

The trick is to do the transcoding fast enough so, by the time one `.mp4` file is finished playing, the next one is available; in other words, the transcoding should take less than a second per second of footage. Ideally, it would take significantly less than that, to account for varying processing power on different devices.

**To clarify, when I say `.mp4`, I *don't* mean fragmented `.mp4` files.**

---

If transcoding to some other format is faster, that might be fine, too. For example, I know the `.mkv` format is playable. I'm still exploring the full range of available formats.

### What I've Tried

I tested transcoding 1 `.ts` file into an `.mp4` file, and unfortunately it took about 6 seconds when the file was about 4 seconds long. That was with [ffmpeg-wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm). I was hoping the JavaScript bridge might be slowing it down and that batching several `.ts` segments in 1 call might help.

##### Command

```
ffmpeg -i test.ts test.mp4
```

##### Log

```
[info] run FS.writeFile test.ts <349304 bytes binary file>
log.js:15 [info] run ffmpeg command: -i test.ts test.mp4
log.js:15 [fferr] ffmpeg version v0.9.0-2-gb11e5c1495 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
log.js:15 [fferr]   built with emcc (Emscripten gcc/clang-like replacement) 2.0.8 (d059fd603d0b45b584f634dc2365bc9e9a6ec1dd)
log.js:15 [fferr]   configuration: --target-os=none --arch=x86_32 --enable-cross-compile --disable-x86asm --disable-inline-asm --disable-stripping --disable-programs --disable-doc --disable-debug --disable-runtime-cpudetect --disable-autodetect --extra-cflags='-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -I/src/build/include -O3 --closure 1' --extra-cxxflags='-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -I/src/build/include -O3 --closure 1' --extra-ldflags='-s USE_PTHREADS=1 -I/src/build/include -O3 --closure 1 -L/src/build/lib' --pkg-config-flags=--static --nm=llvm-nm --ar=emar --ranlib=emranlib --cc=emcc --cxx=em++ --objcc=emcc --dep-cc=emcc --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-zlib --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopus --enable-libwebp --enable-libass --enable-libfribidi
log.js:15 [fferr]   libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
log.js:15 [fferr]   libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
log.js:15 [fferr]   libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
log.js:15 [fferr]   libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
log.js:15 [fferr]   libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
log.js:15 [fferr]   libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
log.js:15 [fferr]   libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
log.js:15 [fferr]   libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
log.js:15 [fferr] Input #0, mpegts, from 'test.ts':
log.js:15 [fferr]   Duration: 00:00:04.00, start: 10.006000, bitrate: 698 kb/s
log.js:15 [fferr]   Program 1 
log.js:15 [fferr]     Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 1411200000.00 tbc
log.js:15 [fferr]     Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
log.js:15 [fferr] Stream mapping:
log.js:15 [fferr]   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
log.js:15 [fferr]   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] using cpu capabilities: none!
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
log.js:15 [fferr] Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
log.js:15 [fferr]   Metadata:
log.js:15 [fferr]     encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
log.js:15 [fferr]     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc
log.js:15 [fferr]     Metadata:
log.js:15 [fferr]       encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
log.js:15 [fferr]     Side data:
log.js:15 [fferr]       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
log.js:15 [fferr]     Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
log.js:15 [fferr]     Metadata:
log.js:15 [fferr]       encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac
log.js:15 [fferr] frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.38 bitrate=   1.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.521x    
log.js:15 [fferr] frame=   47 fps= 27 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.09 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=1.22x    
log.js:15 [fferr] frame=   57 fps= 25 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.51 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=1.13x    
log.js:15 [fferr] frame=   67 fps= 24 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.96 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=1.08x    
log.js:15 [fferr] frame=   77 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.37 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=1.03x    
log.js:15 [fferr] frame=   89 fps= 23 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.96 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=1.04x    
log.js:15 [fferr] frame=   96 fps= 15 q=-1.0 Lsize=      60kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 122.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=0.646x    
log.js:15 [fferr] video:55kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 7.249582%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] frame I:1     Avg QP:17.20  size: 31521
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] frame P:24    Avg QP:16.17  size:   735
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] frame B:71    Avg QP:27.68  size:    91
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  0.0%  3.1% 95.8%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] mb I  I16..4: 26.2% 56.4% 17.4%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.2%  0.0%  P16..4:  3.5%  0.4%  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:95.4%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  1.6%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:98.3%  L0:31.0% L1:69.0% BI: 0.0%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] 8x8 transform intra:56.5% inter:59.4%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 17.4% 15.4% 7.5% inter: 0.2% 0.4% 0.0%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] i16 v,h,dc,p: 29% 63%  1%  7%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 51% 31% 14%  0%  2%  1%  1%  0%  1%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 26% 45% 11%  2%  3%  2%  4%  2%  4%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] i8c dc,h,v,p: 76% 17%  6%  1%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] ref P L0: 89.5%  1.6%  6.7%  2.3%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] ref B L0: 38.5% 60.9%  0.6%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] ref B L1: 97.7%  2.3%
log.js:15 [fferr] [libx264 @ 0x1f5f080] kb/s:111.08
log.js:15 [fferr] [aac @ 0x1f48100] Qavg: 65536.000
log.js:15 [ffout] FFMPEG_END
log.js:15 [info] run FS.readFile test.mp4
(index):38 Time elapsed: 6345 (This one's my own code.)
[info] run FS.readFile test.mp4
```

(I'm running this on the browser. For the purposes of this question, consider the HTML player unavailable for use.)

---

I also tested feeding the HLS live-stream URL as input to ffmpeg and outputting a single `.mp4` file, but I couldn't play it until I ended the live-stream and ffmpeg finished downloading it.

This one I ran on the (Windows) PC; not the browser.

##### Command

```
ffmpeg -i https://stream.mux.com/lngMYGqNpHhYg2ZXqpH8WODVGzuenaZuhckdyunGpzU.m3u8 -acodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

##### Log

The log is too large and StackOverflow won't let me paste it here, so I uploaded it to PasteBin: https://pastebin.com/FqvPQ1DZ

Comment: What ffmpeg command did you try? Share its log.

Comment: @Gyan My bad. I've updated the question with commands and logs.

Comment: It would be way way easier to find a video player that supports hls. It's very common. Transcoding is very complicated in my opinion.

Comment: @BentOnCoding The problem is that I'm building the app in a game engine, and I'll export it to WebGL. The video has to be viewed in a 3D space -- e.g. on a wall -- so I can't use a standard HTML player and, say, hls.js. The game engine's built-in video player doesn't support `.ts` files, so it's either convert them to a playable format or build a compatible player myself.

Comment: You don't have access to the source before it was transcoded?

Comment: It's a livestream, so technically no. I've figured out a solution to my problem, but it's remuxing each .ts file into a .mp4 file, not transcoding them into one, larger .mp4.